# Ti.UI.iPad.SplitWindow update layout or hide/show detailView on orientationchange?

Tags: orientation, titanium, appcelerator, ipad

When using the [Ti.UI.iPad.SplitWindow](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPad.SplitWindow-object) what is the best(cleanest looking) way to update the `detailView`?

The options I can think of are changing the positions of elements in the `detailView` event or to `show()/hide()` vs `open()/close()` on an `orientationchange` event. I know that using the native UI components on the iPad should dynamically update to the layout width/height of the iPad but in my case the content on each `detailView` will have it's child objects positions updated on `orientationchange`. I'm just trying to get the smoothest from your all experiences. Even if I have to build custom animations I just want to start this correct from the beginning so no current code exists yet. Thus none included.

I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate as I searched before I ask but there are no Titanium based questions on this topic I can find. [Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299244/how-to-change-layout-on-orientation-change-for-titanium-ipad) but still different to what I'm asking.

Comment: can you provide an example of what kind of objects are in the detailed view that cannot be positioned through the standard mechanisms of the framework? Just trying to understand the question better.

Comment: Sure. A custom built calendar(view) and photos(imageView) envisioned at this point, however it's likely to change/be added to in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoothest experience will be delivered by changing the least. I don't know what animations you are envisioning, but I would nudge you towards keeping it simple.

Here's a quick example of an orientation change in an iPad app I built recently. I had a bunch of images in a view with layout: 'horizontal'. Due to a [nice bug](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-3256), the images wrapped automatically. When the user reoriented the device, I animated the width of the view, and the images automatically and animatedly resorted themselves.

I've also had some clients at a large corporation get their hearts set on really complicated changes to the layout whenever the user reoriented the device. This resulted in a really unsatisfactory app that took 10-20 seconds to reorient. We made a lot of optimizations, and a lot of improvements in both their code and the underlying framework, but the heart of the problem was the complex design.

Take the time to consider if you really need complicated changes every time the user reorients, and how much benefit you are offering to your users. Also consider the cost to the user (not just to the device) of presenting them with a new UI.

Past that, you're probably not going to get too many answers until you put some experimentation in to this. If you come back with some code and some questions to go along with it, I can reformulate my answer to better pinpoint your situation.

Hope this helps! -Dawson

Comment: For some reason the `splitview` hides itself before the `orientationchange` fires on the device(simulator works) so I ended up doing a `Ti.App.fireEvent` for each `orietationchange` through the `splitview` `detail` and `master` views. As you mentioned I used very little animation to get things moving smoothly. Thanks for your answer :-)